# How to group total hours/day for start/finish data (multiple entries per day, some crossing midnight)?

Tags: mysql, date, datediff

I want to know how to get the exact hours between two dates in current date.

my table;

```
id | start      | s_clock   | finish      | f_clock
---------------------------------------------------
1  | 2017-11-10 | 22:00     | 2017-11-11  | 03:00
2  | 2017-11-11 | 09:00     | 2017-11-11  | 10:00
```

Expected result:

```
day        | total_hours 
--------------------------
2017-11-10 | 02:00            -- sum of all hours spent on 2017-11-10
2017-11-11 | 04:00            -- sum of all hours spent on 2017-11-11
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check if your start day is the previous day of finish day. If so add together: delta from s_clock to 24:00 + delta of 0:00 to f:clock.  If not, simple compute delta from f_clock to s_clock. Show your SQL if problems arise.

Comment: Why should 2017-11-11 give you 4:00 ?  there is only 1 hour between 9:00 and 10:00. See my answer for last comments SQL code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to find 3 hour between 00:00 and 03:00 (in 2017-11-11) + 1 hour between 9:00 and 10:00 (in 2017-11-11)  = total 4 hour for 2017-11-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) as table or field names.

`start` is one of them.

```
create table times ( startt date, s_time time, finish date, f_time time);

insert into times
values 
( "2017-11-10" , "22:00", "2017-11-11" , "03:00"),
( "2017-11-11" , "09:00", "2017-11-11" , "10:00");

select time(sum(delta_on_day)),on_day  -- comment line to see ungrouped results
from -- comment line to see ungrouped results
(   -- comment line to see ungrouped results
  (
    select * 
    ,  timediff(time("24:00"), s_time)  as delta_on_day       
    ,  startt as on_day  
    from times 
    where startt < finish
  )
  UNION ALL 
  (
    select * 
    ,  timediff(f_time, time("0:0"))  as delta_on_day       
    ,  finish as on_day  
    from times 
    where startt < finish
  )
  UNION ALL 
  (
    select * 
    ,  timediff(f_time, s_time)  as delta_on_day       
    ,  startt as on_day  
    from times 
    where startt = finish
  )
) as tbl -- comment line to see ungrouped results
group by on_day -- comment line to see ungrouped results
```

see fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/189e21f/38

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for saving my hours.